# Regex to replace <head> from document

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm trying to strip a tag from a document to help my XML parser parse it, but my Regex isn't working. Here's what I have:

```
stripHead = new RegExp('<HEAD[\s\S]*?\/HEAD>')
doc = doc.replace(stripHead, '')
```

The relevant part of the doc:

```
<SAMI>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>TEST_Eclipse_SMI</TITLE>
<SAMIParam>
      Media {TEST_Eclipse_SMI.wav}
  Metrics {time:ms;}
  Spec {MSFT:1.0;}
</SAMIParam>    <STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--
     P { font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; color: white; background-color: black; text-align: center; }
     .ENUSCC { name: English; lang: en-US ; SAMIType: CC ; }
-->
</STYLE>
    </HEAD>
<BODY>
```

Regex101 seems to think this matches fine, but it's not replacing anything.

Comment: Regular expressions generally only match a single line at a time.  Your example shows multiple lines that you want to match between, so I don't think that's going to work.

Comment: Either `stripHead = new RegExp('<HEAD[\\s\\S]*?/HEAD>')` or `stripHead = /<HEAD[\s\S]*?\/HEAD>/`

Comment: In JS I don't think there is any difference between double and single quoting except that you have to escape the delimiter inside the quote. Except for that, everything is either un-escaped or if it's a special form like `\t` or `\n` it inserts the control code. So your regex string would be `'<HEAD[\\s\\S]*?/HEAD>'`

Comment: Escaping the backslashes fixed it. You should submit that as an answer.